# How to get file name when user select a file via <input type="file" />?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I've seen similar questions before,which ends up with no solution,because of security reasons.

But today I see hostmonster has successfully implemented this,when I open a ticket and attach a file in their backend.

It works both with firefox and IE(version 8 to be exact).

I've verified it's exactly client side scripting,no request is sent(with firebug).

Now,can we re-consider this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "get a file name"? Isn't the file name obvious, because the user just selected it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can get the *file name*, but you cannot get the full client file-system path.

Try to access to the `value` attribute of your file `input` on the `change` event.

Most browsers will give you only the *file name*, but there are exceptions like IE8 which will give you a *fake* path like: `"C:\fakepath\myfile.ext"` and older versions (*IE <= 6*) which actually will give you the full client file-system path (due its lack of security).

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function () {
  alert('Selected file: ' + this.value);
};
```

Comment: I'm getting `C:\fakepath\...` in chrome, but it's fine for my purposes.  Thanks.

Comment: This is about security reason. Web sites must not learn user's folder path.

Comment: Can clean it up like this: `f = f.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');`

Comment: And what about in IE?

Comment: Capture event in the handler function and then use evt.target.files[0].name.

Comment: Olzak's comment is the best answer

Comment: Thanks for the best practice example @JanekOlszak

Comment: You can also use this to show only file name instead of `C:\fakepath\...`.
you can write 
`document.getElementById("id_name").onchange = function(){ document.getElementById("input_id").innerText = document.getElementById("id_name").files[0].name;
  };`

Answer (score 77):

You can use the next code:

JS

```
    function showname () {
      var name = document.getElementById('fileInput'); 
      alert('Selected file: ' + name.files.item(0).name);
      alert('Selected file: ' + name.files.item(0).size);
      alert('Selected file: ' + name.files.item(0).type);
    };
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple onchange="showname()"/>
    </p>    
</body>
```

Comment: You set input id="name" and call it name.files....? Are you seriouse? Why not id="fileInput" or whatever which make sense?

Answer (score 8):

just tested doing this and it seems to work in firefox & IE

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function alertFilename()
            {
                var thefile = document.getElementById('thefile');
                alert(thefile.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="file" id="thefile" onchange="alertFilename()" />
            <input type="button" onclick="alertFilename()" value="alert" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's interesting. When I do it I get `C:\fakepath\background.jpg`. Literally that.

Answer (score 8):

I'll answer this question via **Simple Javascript** that is supported in all browsers that I have tested so far *(IE8 to IE11, Chrome, FF etc).*

Here is the code.

```js
function GetFileSizeNameAndType()
        {
        var fi = document.getElementById('file'); // GET THE FILE INPUT AS VARIABLE.

        var totalFileSize = 0;

        // VALIDATE OR CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
        if (fi.files.length > 0)
        {
            // RUN A LOOP TO CHECK EACH SELECTED FILE.
            for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++)
            {
                //ACCESS THE SIZE PROPERTY OF THE ITEM OBJECT IN FILES COLLECTION. IN THIS WAY ALSO GET OTHER PROPERTIES LIKE FILENAME AND FILETYPE
                var fsize = fi.files.item(i).size;
                totalFileSize = totalFileSize + fsize;
                document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML
                +
                '<br /> ' + 'File Name is <b>' + fi.files.item(i).name
                +
                '</b> and Size is <b>' + Math.round((fsize / 1024)) //DEFAULT SIZE IS IN BYTES SO WE DIVIDING BY 1024 TO CONVERT IT IN KB
                +
                '</b> KB and File Type is <b>' + fi.files.item(i).type + "</b>.";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('divTotalSize').innerHTML = "Total File(s) Size is <b>" + Math.round(totalFileSize / 1024) + "</b> KB";
    }
```

```html
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="file" multiple onchange="GetFileSizeNameAndType()" />
    </p>

    <div id="fp"></div>
    <p>
        <div id="divTotalSize"></div>
    </p>
```

*Please note that we are displaying filesize in KB (Kilobytes). To get in MB divide it by 1024 * 1024 and so on*.

It'll perform file outputs like these on selecting
[image: Snapshot of a sample output of this code]

Answer (score 3):

This is based on a comment under the accepted answer, but easiest might be:

```
$(".fileUploader").on("change", function(e){
   console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
})
```

Or iterate if you have mutliple file selection enabled on that input. Assumes `<input class="fileUploader" ....>`.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up the `C:\fakepath\`

I add `.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', ' ')` to replace it with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

This works clean for me, no `C:\fakepath\` :)

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function () {
  alert('Selected file: ' + this.files[0].name);
};
```