# file path from input tags in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I pick the file path from an input tag in javascript? For example:

```
<input id="file" type="file" onchange="getpath()" />
```

Comment: If by "pick" you mean *set* it, then absolutely not. If you mean "read" then all that's available is the file name, not the path;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get at the full path to the file (which would reveal information about the structure of files on the visitor’s computer). Browsers instead generate a fake path that is exposed as the input’s `value` property. It looks like this (for a file named "file.ext"):

```
C:\fakepath\file.ext
```

You could get just the filename by splitting up the fake path like this:

```
input.onchange = function(){
    var pathComponents = this.value.split('\\'),
        fileName = pathComponents[pathComponents.length - 1];
    alert(fileName);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in some older browsers, but in correct implementations, the Javascript security model will prevent you from reading the path.

Comment: other methods? via flash or other?

Comment: @Omega - Using a 3rd-party plugin (Flash or Java) to make a richer client / app can be used to grab the client-side file path, but in all cases, it is a security risk to the client and should require additional privilege escalation. A more important question is _why_ do you need the client-side path?

Comment: @Omega - You certainly can do it with a signed Java applet. I hope it is not possible with Flash. If it is, I wouldn't count on it to keep working in future versions.