# Get File path form Html upload button in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Basically i'm trying to get path(c:/User/user/Desktop/filename.txt) of a file from where it is uploaded(HTML Home page) and print it on the servlet .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563191/file-path-from-input-tags-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you ,sir for getting me solution