# open file dialog box in javascript and get the value of the selected file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to click an Asp.net button which opens a file dialog, select a file and pass the file name to a textbox using javascript, i really do not know how to go about this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, first look at HTML and how to let users input files

Comment: this has nothing to do with [tag:asp.net] or [tag:c#]

Comment: Look into [how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file) for help.

Comment: One way is to cover the file input with an other element using some CSS. [An example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J57zZ/4/) for modern browsers (not working in IE<11). Alternatively you can hide the input and [click it programmatically](http://jsfiddle.net/E93Ps/1/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your input file tag is fileUploadTAG ,then try this and u will get the path of the file

```
document.getElementById("FileUploadTAG").value
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, how do i open the dialog first before getting the value of the selected file (using your code)

Comment: You will get a [fakepath of the file](http://jsfiddle.net/J57zZ/) or the file name only. IE gives the path when run locally though.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu i get that part, but how do i combine opening the dialog with a input type=" button" and getting the value of the input type="file"?

Comment: thanks @teemu didnt knew ,  and  you have to give tag as <input type="file">