# jQuery - change input file name after file added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>Curriculum vitae</legend>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <div class="file-well" onclick="alertFilename()">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="fileSelect(event)" />
            <span id="filewelllabel">click here or drag and drop<br/></span>
            <span id="filewelllabel">one file only (.pdf, .doc, .docx, .docm)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

that's my drag and drop area (also clickable to manually select).

below that I got

```
<b id = "selected_file_file" class="span3" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; "> NAME HERE </b>
```

I need to update NAME HERE to selected input file name just after it is selected. I tried some queries from:

[How to get file name when user select a file via <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file)

and some other using onChange function but it didnt work for me. Nothing happened.

How can I change displayed name after file is selected?

@edit

```
 <%-- drag and drop kolorowanie --%>

    $(function () {
        $('.file-well input').on('change', function (e) {
            console.log('change!');
            $(e.target).parent().removeClass('hover');
            $(e.target).parent().addClass('filled');

        });
        $('.file-well input').on('dragover', function (e) {
            console.log('dragover');
            $(e.target).parent().addClass('hover');
        });
        $('.file-well input').on('dragleave', function (e) {
            console.log('dragleave');
            $(e.target).parent().removeClass('hover');
        });
    });
    <%-- /drag and drop kolorowanie --%>
```

any1?

Comment: Do u Know An ID should be unique within a page

Comment: What is your JavaScript code?

Comment: alertFilename() at this moment is empty