# How to set value in input type file from input hidden type using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, input-type-file

I have two type of input one is file type and second is hidden type. I have value in hidden type and i want to set value in file type.

This code use in drag and drop file upload. If hidden type input send file all attribute that is good for me because i need file attribute in submit function. How to get file name and lastmodifydate etc....

```
<form action="/upload?X-Progress-ID=1" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" id="form_upload" target="iframe_upload" style="display:none;">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" data-buttonText="" onchange="submitForm()" class="filestyle" data-badge="false"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="filesender" id="filesender" >
</form>
```

Comment: In your code I don't see value in your hidden input. And for security reasons it is forbidden to write value in input file, you can read value but not write into it.
I think your real goal is to get the filename from the inputfile and put it in the hidden input ?

Comment: You can check this answer on stackoverflow, It should help you : [link to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2189712/5384802)

Comment: Hi  Gueras Arnaud, I have file in hidden input but hidden input don't get file name and some other attribute than if i set hidden input file into inputfile then i get all attribute..

Comment: I am able to get file name when file in inputfile but i can't able to get file name when file in hidden input

Comment: How to access file name and other attribute from input type is hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set data using drag and drop in input hidden filed.