# How to access file name and other attribute from input type is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

If I submit a hidden file How can I access `<input type="hidden">` tag's `file name` and file's other attribute.

My main Work on Drag and drop file on server using `Node.js`. If I get a file than can I set this file on input file tag.If can I set this file on input file tag dynamic than I will solve this problem.

Comment: _I submit a hidden file_ you mean to say `type="hidden"` or `type="file"` which is hidden?

Comment: Check forAnswer [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384699/how-to-set-value-in-input-type-file-from-input-hidden-type-using-javascript/35889340#35889340)

Answer (score 0):

To get value from input type after form submit,please refer following example-

```
  <form action="successfulbooking.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="date" value="hidden_value">  
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </form>
```

successfulbooking.php

```
<?php
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        // add code here
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is done by adding normal input file it's opacity and add layer under it contains your own text or image as you like this will work and when you submit the form it will work

```
<html><head>
<style>
.inputFile{
opacity:0;
}

.inputFile:before{
content:"Drag and drop file here";
position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div style="
    background-image: url(&quot;download.jpg&quot;);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
">

<input class="inputFile" type="file" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 32px;
    /* z-index: -1; */
    opacity: 0;
">
</div>

</form>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I have a file. How to send this file on server using drag and drop in node.js , Javascript, Ajax.

Comment: in case you want to submit file using ajax use the following libarary http://malsup.com/jquery/form/  i used it before in file uploading ajax and it works fine