# Feed the name result of file select in an input tag

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

In this form I have the field file name in which I want to have the user either type the file name he wants or select a file name from his file system. So I want him to select his file and then the file name to fill in the text of input tag. Is this possible? Can you see any obvious mistakes I can correct?

```
<div class="modal-body">                                                     
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="modal-add-tech-file-name" required>
                   <span>
                       <form>
                            <label for="file-add-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Select file
                            </label>
                            <input id="file-add-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
                       </form>
                  </span>
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>                         
</div>
```

This is the code from the file that handles the buttons and makes ajax requests.

```
$('#file-add-upload').change(function() {
    var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
    var file = $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name;
    $('#modal-add-tech-file-name').val(data(file)); 
    //$("#modal-edit-tech-file-name").prev('label').text(file);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file name when user select a file via <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file)

Comment: @Farahmand  But I am posting specific code.... How can a question with no code at all be the same with mine?

Comment: @CBrow this is not the same question... I have posted specific code... the question you are referring has no code at all.

Comment: generally it means the answer/solution is duplicated or the gist of the problem, not that your code is duplicated

Comment: @atmd thanks for all your comments but since I post some specific code then it means I couldn't find the answer to the generic post you are redirecting me to.

Comment: Stop it with the “but I posted specific code” nonsense, please and thank you. The purpose of this site is not to deliver you copy&paste-ready code for whatever problem you might have - but to give you the basic information you need to implement this yourself. And in that spirit, _yes, those are duplicates_.

Comment: @CBROE I wish when you were starting posting questions here the answer you got were similar to the one you have me... it was as simple as the answer below (it was something I overlooked)... thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong id. `#file-upload` isn't even referenced in your html. 
I changed it to `#file-add-upload` and got the name of the file by using `$('#file-add-upload').val()`. Afterwards i simply set the filename as value of the textfield by using your code. See the sample below.

```js
$('#file-add-upload').change(function() {
    var filename = $('#file-add-upload').val();
    $('#modal-add-tech-file-name').val(filename); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="modal-add-tech-file-name" required/>
         <span>
            <form>
               <label for="file-add-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
               <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Select file
               </label>
               <input id="file-add-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;"/>
            </form>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```