# Can't upload a custom .swf file for users to run on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have this very basic HTML page where users can play .swf file games. I'm trying to make a page where users can upload their own .swf file and run and play it. I originally took the template from another post, and I just wanted to replace the three elements that need the url with the javascript needed to upload it. Currently this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="bitbot.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<style media="screen" type="text/css">html, body { height:100%; background- 
color: #000000;}
body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
#flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><input id="file" target=".swf" type="file" /><button onclick="runFlash()" 
type="button">Run</button></p>

<div id="flashContent"><object align="middle" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d- 
11cf-96b8-444553540000" height="100%" width="100%"><param id="box1" 
name="movie" /><param name="quality" 
value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="play" 
value="true" /><param name="loop" value="true" /><param name="wmode" 
value="window" /><param name="scale" value="default" /><param name="menu" 
value="true" /><param name="devicefont" value="false" /><param name="salign" 
value="" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /><!--[if 
!IE]>--><object height="100%" id="box2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
width="100%"><param id="box3" name="movie" /><param name="quality" 
value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="play" 
value="true" /><param name="loop" value="true" /><param name="wmode" 
value="window" /><param name="scale" value="default" /><param name="menu" 
value="true" /><param name="devicefont" value="false" /><param name="salign" 
value="" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /><!--<! 
[endif]--><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><span 
contenteditable="false" tabindex="-1"><span contenteditable="false" 
tabindex="-1"><img alt="Get Adobe Flash player" data-widget="image" src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" /></span></span> </a> <!--[if !IE]>--></object><!--<![endif]--></object></div>
</body>
<script>
function runFlash() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  var swf = fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
  document.getElementById("box1").value = swf;
  document.getElementById("box2").data = swf;
  document.getElementById("box3").value = swf;
}
</script>
</html>
```

I wanted to make it so that the var swf would have the url, but it returned as undefined. I also tried

```
var swf = fr.result;
```

but that returned as nothing. Could someone please help me? This isn't for a professional website, I mostly just help out with code from other friends.

Comment: Two mistakes. First, **FileReader.readAsText** is an asynchronous operation while you are treating it as synchronous: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText Second (and mainly), HTML tags must contain the URL of the SWF file rather than its content in text representation. So even if you fix the sync/async issue, it won't work anyway.

Comment: @Organis I see what you mean, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189615/how-to-get-file-name-when-user-select-a-file-via-input-type-file It won't work if user selects an SWF from any other folder than the same one where your HTML page resides. Alternately, you can make the upload form that uploads the selected SWF file to server and forms the relevant HTML tags (you'll probably need some server-side scripting too).