# How to print the name of the input file next to the upload button in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print the name of the file next to the upload button but for some reason, it's not working. Currently, the upload button works but I would like to have the name of the file print next to it.

Here is how my html looks like

[image: button]

And here is the css part of the one of the upload-lable class

```
.upload-label{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    background: #39D2B4;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: all .4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-label:hover{
    background: #34495E;
    color: #39D2B4;
}
```

## HTML

```
<form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-label">
        Choose...
    </label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide the working code with HTML

Comment: You would require javascript to do that.

Comment: possibly this is what you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/2189615/6550949

Comment: @Mangesh I just updated the post with the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file name by either accessing the `value` of the `<input>` element, or by listening to the upload event (`change`).

Please notice that in any case you'd have to get the file name **after** the upload, so it's probably a better idea to use a listener.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('imageUpload');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);      // First print
  console.log(inputElement.value);  // Second print
});
```

```html
<form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-label">
        Choose...
    </label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
</form>
```

Then you can inject the `fileName` to an element (i.e. with ID `output`) using various method, for example:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerText = fileName
```

Comment: @upendra Yes, the code is in JavaScript. I've used StackOverflow's code snippet format because I thought it'd be more clear ;)

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help