# Bootstrap 3.0 input type of file in an input group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap 3.x I can create a form with an input field type of "file" as shown in the Bootstrap documentation:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  </div>
<form>
```

However, I can't figure out a way to put the "file" input field within an input group so the input field is on the left and the browse button on the right, all inline.  Something like the following just places the above inside a text box with the browse button to the left of the input field:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suspect I can't use the standard Bootstrap CSS to do put a file input field inline, but thought I would ask.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917710/how-do-i-position-the-file-input-button-on-the-right-hand-side-inside-the-textfi) might help.

Comment: Thank you!  I was focused on Bootstrap in my search and didn't see this link.  The info in that link and the links they reference explain what I'm dealing with and should provide a solution.  I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: check this http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/