# Modify jQuery Mobile (jqm) file upload button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am looking to modify the Standard file upload button [provided by JQuery Mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/forms/) to custom file upload button. (see below) 
Tried several ways to override the styling with not much success. 
Can someone please suggest how I can achieve this ?

Standard file upload button

[image: Standard file upload button]

Custom File Upload Buttom

[image: Custom File Upload Buttom]

```
<style>
div.fileinputs {
            position: relative;
        }

        div.fakefile {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        div.fakefile input[type=button] {
            /* enough width to completely overlap the real hidden file control */
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 426px;
        }

        div.fileinputs input.file {
            position: relative;
            text-align: right;
            -moz-opacity:0 ;
            filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }
</style>


<script>
$(document).on('pageinit','#address_form',function (event){     
   $('#upload_button').parent('.ui-btn').css('width','334%');
})
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="address_form">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class='container_12'>
        <div class='grid_12 fileinputs' >
        <input type="file"  class="file" style='opacity:0;' />
        <div class="fakefile" style='padding: 1.8%;' >
            <input id='upload_button' type="button" value="Upload" style='' />
        </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have tried? I dont think it is possible without using another code of jquery.

Comment: I tried suggestion on this link, but had issues setting the button size to suit responsive web design. (I will add the code to my question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532733/styling-input-type-file

Comment: Have you tried adding a label for the upload field, then hiding the field? Clicking the label activates the field in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I used this in a project recently, this should do you fine - cross browser too.

html

```
<div id="UGC_sign_up">
<form id="form" name="frmUpload" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="browse">
<!-- your button image below id image -->
<img id="image" src="upload.png" onclick="HandleFileButtonClick();" />
</form>
</div>
```

css
You can position as you want but example I used below:

```
#UGC_sign_up{
display: none;
position: relative;
}
#form{
position:relative; display: block;
width:200px; height:200px;
}
#image{
position: absolute;
top: 10px; left:20px;
display: block;
width:200px; height:150px;
}
```

jquery for adding in the click event to the image from the file button

```
/* associate click of browse button to image */
function HandleFileButtonClick(){ /* this click event is in the image */
    document.frmUpload.myFile.click(); /* "myFile" is name field for the browse input button */
}
```

Comment: Not a jQuery Mobile solution - sorry

Comment: Warning - click() won't work in Chrome (or Safari - I believe) - the label solution described in the comments to the original question does work for Chrome - I haven't tried this with other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest AND PRETTIEST way to do this is by simply hiding the file input field and triggering a click on that field from another button that you can style exactly as you wish. Here's how I do it:

**Basic HTML & Javascript Example**

```
<input id="csv" type="file" style="display:none;" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('csv').click();">Select</a>
```

**Basic HTML & jQuery Example**

```
<input id="csv" type="file" style="display:none;" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#csv').click();">Select</a>
```

Comment: Again - not a jQuery Mobile solution - sorry

Answer (score -1):

I've had some success with this. I tried having a jQuery mobile button do a $('#id_of_file_input').click(), but this didn't work - I'm using Chrome.

So, I found that a label for a file input will accept a click as well.

So, here is a solution:

```
<input id="upload_media" class="hidden" type="file" onchange="index.handle_upload_media();"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <label for="upload_media" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-open"></span> Upload Media
    </label>
</div>
```

Notes: The input itself is hidden, but the label references it's id. For the button to look right, I had to but the button type and classes in the label - the mouse over works as well.  My handler is the index.handle_upload_media()...

Hope this helps - Andy

Comment: Not much detail in your solution though - nothing more than the other comments.

Comment: I'm not sure what detail you expect - this is an answer to the question. It is a jQuery Mobile solution - as requested - unlike the other answers. Unlike the comment about a label - this also works as a jQuery Mobile button. I have a lot more detail on handling the upload - but that doesn't answer the question...