# Hide the browse button on a input type=file

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to hide the browse button and only leave the text box that works in all browsers?

I have tried setting the margins but they show up different in each browser

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37183065/882337

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, what you can do is a (ugly) workaround, but largely used

1. Create a normal input and a image
2. Create file input with opacity 0
3. When the user click on the image, you simulate a click on the file input
4. When file input change, you pass it's value to the normal input (so user can see the path)

Here you can see a full explanation, along with code:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: I would think that browser might ban this for security in the future.

Comment: I don't see see why this represents such a treat, to be removed. Plus, if browsers ban this now, it would break a lot of pages.

Answer (score 11):

You may just without making the  element hidden, simply make it transparent by making its opacity to 0.

Making the input file hidden will make it STOP working. So DON'T DO THAT..

[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) you can find an example for a transparent Browse operation;

Comment: Uh, that's the same link as the answer above.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "hidden", please specify when you think the input stops working. It sounds weird because when you link a label element to the input, than it basically doesn't matter anymore what you do to the input as long as it remains linked with the label.

Answer (score 10):

```css
        .dropZoneOverlay, .FileUpload {
            width: 283px;
            height: 71px;
        }

        .dropZoneOverlay {
            border: dotted 1px;
            font-family: cursive;
            color: #7066fb;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .FileUpload {
            opacity: 0;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="dropZoneContainer">
            <input type="file" id="drop_zone" class="FileUpload" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" onchange="handleFileSelect(this) " />
            <div class="dropZoneOverlay">Drag and drop your image <br />or<br />Click to add</div>
        </div>
```

I find a good way of achieving this at [Remove browse button from input=file](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1436696227-Remove-browse-button-from-input%3Dfile).

The rationale behind this solution is that it creates a transparent input=file control and creates an layer visible to the user below the file control. The z-index of the input=file will be higher than the layer.

With this, it appears that the layer is the file control itself. But actually when you clicks on it, the input=file is the one clicked and the dialog for choosing file will appear.

Comment: Tech This is the best method. least amount of complexity and least effort I guess.

Comment: Love this answer, helped me so much. No need to implement extra JS.

Answer (score 9):

Below code is very useful to hide default browse button and use custom instead:

```js
(function($) {
  $('input[type="file"]').bind('change', function() {
    $("#img_text").html($('input[type="file"]').val());
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.file-input-wrapper {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 118px;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-input-wrapper>input[type="file"] {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-input-wrapper>.btn-file-input {
  background-color: #494949;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 121px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-input-wrapper:hover>.btn-file-input {
  //background-color: #494949;
}

#img_text {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -80px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="file-input-wrapper">
    <button class="btn-file-input">SELECT FILES</button>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="" />
  </div>
  <span id="img_text"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

As of 2022, modern browsers [support file button pseudo selector](https://caniuse.com/?search=file-selector-button). I was only struggling with Safari v16.1 which didn't work as expected and had to workaround button hiding (`::-webkit-file-upload-button` part).

```css
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
    display: none;
}

input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -100%;
}

input[type=file]::-ms-browse {
    display: none;
}
```

You may also use concise syntax:

```css
::file-selector-button {
    /* ... */
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    /* ... */
}

::-ms-browse {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Came across this question and didn't feel like any of the answers were clean. Here is my solution:

```
<label>
  <span>Select file</span>
  <input type="file" style="display: none">
</label>
```

When you click the label the select file dialog will open. No js needed to make it happen.

You can style the label to look like a button.

Here is an example using w3css and font awesome:

```
<label class="w3-button w3-blue w3-round">
    <span><i class="fas fa-image"></i></span>
    <input type="file" style="display: none" >
</label>
```

Of course you need to add an event listener to the input to detect a file was chosen.

Answer (score 2):

So I found this solution that is very easy to implement and gives a very clean GUI

put this in your HTML

```
<label class="att-each"><input type="file"></label>
```

and this in your CSS

```
label.att-each {
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
background: url("add-file.png") no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

add-file.png can be any graphic you wish to show on the webpage. Clicking the graphic will launch the default file explorer.

Working Example: http://www.projectnaija.com/file-picker17.html

Answer (score 2):

HTML - InputFile component can be hide by writing some css.
Here I am adding an icon which overrides inputfile component.

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <InputFile OnChange="HandleFileSelected" />
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
</label>
```

css-

```
<style>
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-file-upload {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The `InputFile` component seems to be from ASP.NET Core Blazor, instead of standard HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional hint for avoiding too much JavaScript here: if you add a label and style it like the "browse button" you want to have, you could place it over the real browse button provided by the browser or hide the button somehow differently. By clicking the label the browser behavior is to open the dialog to browse for the file (don't forget to add the "for" attribute on the label with value of the id of the file input field to make this happen). That way you can customize the button in almost any way you want.

In some cases, it might be necessary to add a second input field or text element to display the value of the file input and hide the input completely as described in other answers. Still the label would avoid to simulate the click on the text input button by JavaScript.

BTW a similar hack can be used for customizing checkboxes or radiobuttons. by adding a label for them, clicking the label causes to select the checkbox/radiobutton. The native checkbox/radiobutton then can be hidden somewere and be replaced by a custom element.

Answer (score 1):

Just add negative text intent as so:

```
input[type=file] {
  text-indent: -120px;
}
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Hi, this solution does not work for every language, because that button depends on the language selected in the browser

Comment: Yes. I completely agree with you. Besides being not stable this solution is extremely simple and fast to implement. Hence I used it once and I can imagine certain use cases. I would appreciate edit to this answer explaining all gotchas with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this works for me (when I place inside a button tag).

```
.button {
    position: relative;

    input[type=file] {
            color: transparent;
            background-color: transparent;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 100;
        }
}
```

Only tested in Chrome (macOS Sierra).

Answer (score 0):

the best way for it

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<label for="file" class="file-trigger">Click Me</label>
```

And you can style your "label" element

```
#file { 
   display: none;
}
.file-trigger {
/* your style */
}
```

Comment: This removes the name of the uploaded file.