# How to style a asp:FileUpload button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, file-upload

I have a situation where it's been required that the Browse/SelectFile/etc button be styled to match our conventional styles that are everywhere else.

Previously I tried to just hide the default control and expose my own Browse and Save buttons, but I've found that doing `style="visibility:hidden;width:0px"` in a FileUpload control style breaks the control for IE.

So how can I style the stock asp:FileUpload button(s)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried style="display:none;" instead?

Comment: Same effect as what I have.  Works fine in Chrome/FF, but IE does not like it.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?  Otherwise, if you can use Jquery, it has a .hide() method, which should work similar to display:none, but might work better in IE.  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: IE 9.0.8.  Was this not an issue in earlier version of IE?

Comment: not that i know of, but i've never tried to hide a file upload, other controls i've always been able to hide with display:none; in all browsers.

Comment: after looking around, it seems like you can't style is easily for security reasons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376452/hide-the-browse-button-on-a-input-type-file see last message. there is also a way to get around it in the same link, the one marked answer