# Hide browse button inside file input

Tags: css, file, button, input

So far I managed to make my upload button act like a file input but now I don't want the browse button anymore and unfortunately I don't know how to get rid of it.[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how this is set up. But try `display: none`

Comment: see if the browse button has a selector you can use - and display:none it.  - else you can make a path selector to it, if you could show your html.

Comment: You could rename your brower button directly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button-of-an-input-type-file

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/5e4ujhj85/ Here is my html input

Answer (score 0):

The best idea for fixing this would be to create a custom file input. This might seem painful at first but is the best way to have full control over your file input design.

Look at https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/ for one of the ways to do this.

Another way involves an ugly work around that is widely used. The thread for the following is [Hide the browse button on a input type=file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376452/hide-the-browse-button-on-a-input-type-file)