# How would one go about styling the input type="file" button?

Tags: html

How would one go about styling the `<input type="file">` button?

Comment: Haven't you tried Google? A couple of searches should've told you that you can't style it directly.

Comment: this is a Duplicate of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't through CSS. You need to use a JavaScript overlay that hides the display of the File Upload.

Look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html for an example

Answer (score 1):

With great difficulty!

In general, you can't style it as you would other elements. Workarounds do exist, but none of them are completely satisfactory.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html