# Styling input type file button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question regarding the styling of the input type file button.
Since I cannot style the file input button, can I make a div that I can style how I want and when I click it , it triggers the input type button which opens the browse window ? If yes, any suggestions how to do it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can probably do that. You should have a go and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling an input type="file" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, this is one of the most used *hacks* for styling file-input.

Take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Tim this is just great, thanks, I will make one just like that thanks :)

Comment: @Beneto It does but that will look different on every browser. Think of chrome which shows you a button with the file name while firefox shows you an input-field with a browse button.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'd would have never of thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

May be you can hide the input element and make use of a div for styling purposes..

```
<input type="file" id="myFileInput" onchange="$('#myFileDiv').text($(this).val());" style="display:none;" />
<div id="myFileDiv" onclick="$('#myFileInput').click();">
    Select File..
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can style the file input with just css

```css
label[for="file-input"] {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="file"] {
  cursor: pointer !Important;
}
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background: #9e2baf;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type="file"]::-ms-browse {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background: #9e2baf;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
                     <label class="file-label" for="input-file">Attach file:</label>
                     <br /> <input type="file" name="attachment[]"  multiple="multiple">
```