# CSS and html: how to style input file in css (aline the text with the choose file button)?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Please see the image above. I have had this problem for a few times. The text never alines with the button. 
How can we change it so that they will aline?

The code is simply:

```
<td><label>Image/Avatar Upload</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="avatar"></td>
```

and the css:

```
input {width: 350px; font-size: 20px; padding: 2px;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen something similar. It's to my understanding that each browser's file upload input is styled differently and is impossible to style yourself. [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900362/styling-input-type-file-button/).

Comment: @tipsywacky the message 'no file chosen', how is it printed and where? Is it in the same cell or do you have any styling for it with CSS?

Comment: the no file chosen is the default message I believe.  It is the same cell. You can see the css that I just added.

Comment: @itsols That's how Chrome renders file inputs (maybe Safari, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  don't bother trying to style file inputs

The long answer: Completely controlling the styling file inputs have eluded us for years.  They have components that fall under what's called *Shadow DOM*.  We can see them, but we can't really touch them.  The newer input elements (date, time, color, etc.) have the same "problem".

It should be noted that not every browser styles file inputs the same way.  If you really *really* want to control this element, you have to *replace* it (google: "replace file input with image").  If you do this, the user will lose the ability to see exactly which file is being uploaded when they're not interacting with the file input element (due to security reasons, the filename will be accessible via JavaScript, but the path won't be).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more detail because your provided code is working fine.

```
<td><label>Image/Avatar Upload</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="avatar"></td>
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wKd5b/)

Comment: my bad, I just added the css.