# Styling input file Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Styling an input type=“file” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

I tried to style an input file.

It works great with Chrome and Safari but not with Firefox.

CSS :

```
input[type="file"] {
   position: absolute; 
   padding: 0px; 
   width: 100%!important; 
   height: 220px; 
   background: #000; 
   top: 0;
   z-index: 3000;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploadfile[]" />
```

Chrome :

[image]

Firefox :
[image]

Do you have a solution for Firefox, please ?

Thanks

Comment: what version of firefox are you using? the attribute selector your using for your input type of file, is only supported in FF 11+

Comment: @ryan I use the last firefox !