# Upload file using text link instad of input

Tags: css, file-upload, input

I know there are a few posts about this already but the answers in some seem to have caused some controversy so, I'm wondering if there's a "foolproof" way of triggering the file upload without using an input field.  Basically what I want to do id to have a div with an Icon & text link which triggers the file upload when you click it. Kind of like:

```
.upload{
padding: 5px 10px 5px 30px;
background: url() center left no-repeat;
}
<div class="upload">(icon) Click here to add a photo</div>
```

Any help or advice would be hugely appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)?

Comment: Because I don't want to style the input, I don't want to use it at all!

Comment: @user2546546 Read the answers again. Some solutions are hiding the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your html this:

```
<input id="article_file_input" type="file" name="article_picture" style="display: none;">
```

And to make anchor:

`<a onclick="$('input[id=article_file_input]').click();">Click here to add files</a>`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to do and it works great