# pseudo classes not working on select and radio element

Tags: html, css

I have a website that works fine in Chrome but in "IE" it breaks.

Two element are breaking:

**1. **Radio Button:**** Here is the code

```
 input[type='radio'] {
width: 100%;
height: 42px;
padding-top: 12px;
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
background-image: url(btn-toggle-up.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

**IE Screenshot:**

[image]

**Chrome Screenshot:**

[image]

**2. Select Element :**  Here is the code

```
select {
height: 42px;
padding-left: 10px;
display: block;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 42px;
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(select-arrow.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}
```

**IE Screenshot:**

[image]

**Chrome Screenshot:**

[image]

Here is the code which I am using

```
select::-ms-expand{display:none;}
::-ms-check{display:none;}
```

After a bit research, I came to this one of the most proper solution to fix both the problems. But it seems I can't get it work on my elements and still the bug is there.

I have tested this in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: Add this to the css 

    input[type='radio'] {
      ...

     -webkit-appearance:none;
    }

Comment: @Rao Thanks for the feedback but I have added this. In a hierarchy I have all the none properties like width:30px; height:30px; margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
 clear: none; cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
 background:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;
 appearance:none; -webkit-appearance:none; -moz-appearance:none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using non-standard `appearance` property, which happens to be supported by Chrome, but not IE. Pseudo elements like `::-ms-expand` and `::-ms-check` will work only in IE 10+.

Form controls are known to be hard to style, so if you want a consistent cross browser appearance, use UI libraries like **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio)** or reconsider styling form controls with your designer.

Comment: That's makes proper sense. I got the answer to this question.... I figured it out yesterday that these Pseudo elements will only work on IE10+. Thanks for your feedback. I have accepted your answer as a perfect solution for my query. Thanks for spending time for my query... Blessings

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty bad idea to try this kind of stuff.
But if you really want to overwrite this basic statement, the best way is to construct with div and specific classes your radio buttons and using jQuery or javascript to set up your form. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button).

Comment: I have to edit with what is provided man; I am afraid I will not be allowed this at this stage of the delivery, but pseudo also seems to  the right way to go.... I think something is missing....