# File Input Button Style with jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI and I notice that the Input File button:

```
<input type="file">
```

can't be styled like other buttons. I found [this plugin](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/style-file-input.html) which looks cool and apparently allows you to put an image instead of the button, but the examples don't show any button styling.

If there's no jQuery to apply the theme style to that button, can I style it myself in CSS?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, with only CSS.

Make a `<form>`, wrap a `<div>` inside it & put your `<input type="file">` in the `<div>`.

To override the default styling of the `<input type="file">`, the main priority is to set the `opacity: 0;` on the input so that the styling comes from the `<div>` css.

---

**UPDATE:**

To get the text from the `<input type="file">` you need a bit of jQuery.

For example, add a paragraph. Then get the text from the input using [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) and set it as the paragraphs text. Updated Fiddle:

---

## Fiddle demo

Comment: It's the simplest solution and I like that it's only CSS, unfortunately you can't see the text with the name of the selected file anymore.

Comment: Yes that is true. Unfortunately, the text is bounded to the button element of the `input`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

Markup:

```
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

Css:

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32f5R/)

**Note:** I have used Bootstrap for styling button (`div.file-upload`).

Comment: There's no need for bootstrap as the css you provided works really well as-is! Bootstrap is only a complementary addition.

Comment: Yes @Emileb i have added `bootstarp` as optional.

Answer (score 3):

May be you want something like this:

### Html:

```
<div id='file'>
   <label id='text'for="inputFile1">No file selected.</label>
   <label for="inputFile1">
       <input type="file" id='inputFile1' class='fileInput'/>
   </label>
</div>
```

### css:

```
input[type="file"] {
    opacity:0;
}
#file {
    background:url('...der_open-add.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#file label {
    padding:0 0 0 35px;
    color:green;
    width:100%;
}
#file #text {
    line-height:32px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0;
    color:green;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

### and jQuery:

```
$('#file input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {
    var o = this.value || 'No file selected.';
    $(this).closest('#file').find('#text').text(o);
});
```

---

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5wsy/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;left:-4px;bottom:-6px;width:16px;  height: 24px;overflow:hidden;">
<img src="/images/attach.jpg" alt="" title="Add Attachment" style="height:24px;width:16px; position: relative;top: 1px; left: 0px;"/>
<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="upload" style=" opacity: 0;font-size: 50px;width:16px; filter:alpha(opacity: 0);  position: relative; top: -22px; left: -1px" />
</div>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k6zBQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution:
Put the input button in a div with css display:none
Make your button anyway you want and bind a function that trigger the invisible input button.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <form id="fileupload">
        <input type="file" class="upload" name="newfile"/>
    </form>
</div>

<span id="browser">Click this line to browse all your awesome files</span>

JQUERY:
$("#browser").on('click', function(){
    $(".upload").click();       
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moonworker/os3h6v9c/)