# Open file via <a> click instead of <input>?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to front-end development, and I'm trying to open a file (an .xml file). I have a drop-down menu called File with the structure:

File:

- Open
- Save

I want that when I press the "Open" tab, the file select window appear so I can choose the file. I tried to put an `<input type="file">` inside the `<a>` element like that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openFile()"><input type="file">Open<a>
```

But a huge button appears next to it, and I don't want that to appear, I just want It behaviour.

Here is a little fiddle to show the scenario [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz1wykz7/1/)

Comment: can't put an `<input>` inside an `<a>`, it's invalid

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling an input type="file" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Comment: Aug, I'm not sure if It is duplicated What I want is something like www.draw.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hide the input dialog and use JavaScript to select it once the link is clicked (I'm assuming that's what you were trying to do in the Fiddle):

```js
function openFile() {
  document.querySelector("li input").click();
}
```

```css
li input {
  visibility: none;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <!--Button File-->
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button>File</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <input type="file" /><a href="#" onclick="openFile()">Open</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Save</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/8cyL71ov/), if you prefer.</sub>

Comment: AstroCB, yes, It is exactly what I want. I'm also new to stackoverflow. So Should I mark you comment as the one that solved my problem or Should I mark as already have an answer as the guy called "AUG", said in the comment above?

Comment: @Rafael If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted. However, [it's up to you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can get an open file dialog is to use an `<input type="file">` or a browser plugin.  Assuming you want to avoid a plugin, that means you'll have to do some clever styling to change the appearance of the button.  One technique is to position the button above the link, and make it almost completely transparent.