# CSS style works on chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

The following code runs successfully on chrome browser but not work on Mozilla firefox.

How can I make the below code work on all browsers

```css
.customfile {
    width: 371px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="file"].customfile::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: -99px;
    background-color: #8bc243;
    height: 29px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="form-block-small block-right">
 <span class="gray14">Proof documents</span><br>
 <input type="file" name="proof_documents" id="proof_documents" class="customfile valid">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080644/customize-the-file-button-for-image-upload/16080910#16080910 ?

Comment: Yes, but the answer of it can't display the chose file name @ChrisLear

Comment: `-webkit-file-upload-button` is a webkit only feature. Firefox is made by Mozilla and thus doesn't have it. Have you tried [this alternate method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button)?

Comment: I'm not sure even the alternative method will help. This is a much-asked and little-answered problem. The best reference is probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413109/how-to-style-html-file-upload-button-with-pure-css-in-firefox

Comment: My preferred method of setting up file inputs is with `<label>` elements. Hide the file input itself, and have a label that points to it, styled however you may please.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `span` element point to the `input file` element, and hide the input itself.

Then, with some JS, put the name (or other info) where your layout needs.

### HTML

```
    <label class="myButton" for="proof_documents">Carica</label> <br>
    <input type="file" name="proof_documents" id="proof_documents" class="customfile valid">
    <span class="name-file"></span>
```

### CSS

```
  #proof_documents {
    display:none;
  }

 .myButton {
   // your stiles!
 }
```

### JS

```
$('#proof_documents').on('change', function(){

  $('.name-file').html('')
  $('.name-file').html(document.getElementById("proof_documents").files[0].name)

});
```

Here is [the demo1](http://jsbin.com/busagifiba/edit?html,css,js,console,output), or [demo2](http://jsbin.com/mawudenute/edit?html,css,output)