# Can I use ng2-file-upload with button instead of a file input?

Tags: file-upload, angular

I'm using [ng2-file-upload](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) (single upload example) and I want to use: `ng2FileSelect` with a button or a div instead of a file input. How can I do this?

I want this to do something like this:

```
<button ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader">Choose file</button>
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

If does not exist a clean way using [ng2-file-upload](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/), do you know an alternative?

Comment: Do you find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 33):

One possible solution is to leverage Angular 2's template variables, and to assign a template variable to the input element;  once done, you can directly invoke methods defined on that input from another element, such as a button.

I did the following in one of my applications;  it works on IE11, Firefox, and Chrome:

```
<button (click)="fileInput.click()" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
<span style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height:0px;border:none;margin:0; padding:0">
     <input type="file" #fileInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
</span>
```

So as you can see, the button is simply calling the #fileInput's click event within its own click event.

Note that I'm burying the input within a **span**, and then hiding the span from view via a bunch of styles, such that only the button is visible.  Also note that applying these styles to the input element directly seemed to cause problems in IE11.

Comment: Great idea!  Your example was a good model that worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Yon can wrap `input[file]` element with label element and hide it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825731/6392181) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/)

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a simple way, you can do it with **label**,  you just have to hide the **input**.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label class="btn custom-input-btn">
<input type="file" name="photo" style="display:none" accept="*" multiple>        
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Files
</label>
```