# How to display file name for custom styled input file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input-field

I have styled a file input using CSS:

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Everything is working fine, but I’d like to display the selected file name. How is this possible using CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling an input type="file" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Comment: If you could put the name attribute in the label - then this could be done with just CSS with the attr() function (generated content can't be added to input elements ). http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/XpmNYZ?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to bind and trigger the change event on the `[type=file]` element and read the files name as:

```js
$('#file-upload').change(function() {
  var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
  var file = $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name;
  $(this).prev('label').text(file);
});
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Comment: @ Jai This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 however for me it didn't work with $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name; but it worked fine with $('#file-upload').files[0].name;

Comment: If your label is after the input then $(this).next('label').text(file);

Answer (score 31):

You need to get name of file when input change and insert it into html. In the code `this.files[0].name` get name of selected file.

```
$("#file-upload").change(function(){
  $("#file-name").text(this.files[0].name);
});
```

```js
$("#file-upload").change(function(){
  $("#file-name").text(this.files[0].name);
});
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
    <label id="file-name"></label>
</form>
```

Also you can do this work using **pure javascript**

```
document.querySelector("#file-upload").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file-name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector("#file-upload").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file-name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
}
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
  <label id="file-name"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use this for multiple file upload also

```js
updateList = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('file');
  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');

  output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
    output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
  }
  output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple 
       onchange="javascript:updateList()" />
<br/>Selected files:
<div id="fileList"></div>
```

Comment: Simple, effective and customizable. Thank You for such a simple yet powerful snippet.
This one did it for me. (L)

Answer (score 8):

You can take the file name like this

```
$('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name
```

Comment: That is right buy isn't perfect. It only get file name and you should use it when input change and set getted name in htm.

Answer (score 4):

Since continues update of browser CSS fix is not effective for all browsers please use JavaScript version for above problem solution.

### Solution 1

**CSS snippets**

```
.wrap-file_upload{position:relative; display:inline-block;}
.wrap-file_upload .btn_colorlayer,.wrap-file_upload:hover .btn_colorlayer{position: absolute; left: 102%; padding-left: 8px; max-width: 120px; white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; color:#d7263d;top: 50%; margin-top: -8px; text-transform: none; pointer-events:none; }
.wrap-file_upload input[type="file"]{opacity: 0; height:40px; display: inline; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 230px; bottom: 0;}
.wrap-file_upload .btn_lbl{pointer-events: none;}
```

**JavaScript snippets**

```
function _updatename(obj){
    var _parentObj = $(obj).parents("[data-uploadfield]");
    _parentObj.addClass("wrap-file_upload");
    if(!_parentObj.find(".btn_colorlayer").length){
        _parentObj.append("<span class='btn_colorlayer'></span>")
    }
    var _tempname = "";
    if( $(obj).val() != "" && typeof( $(obj).val())!='undefined'){
        _tempname =  $(obj).val().split('\\');
        _tempname = _tempname[_tempname.length-1];
    }

    var _name = _tempname ||  $(obj).parents("[data-uploadfield]").attr("data-uploadfield") || "No file chosen";
    _parentObj.find(".btn_colorlayer").attr("title",_name).text(_name);
}

if($("[data-uploadfield]").length){
    $("[data-uploadfield]").each(function(i){
        _updatename($(this).find("input[type='file']"));
    });
}

$(document).on("click","[data-uploadfield] input[type='file']",function(){
    _updatename($(this));
});

$(document).on("change","[data-uploadfield] input[type='file']",function(){
    _updatename($(this));
});

//  Enable Custom Control for Ajax called pages
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event,request,settings){
    if($("[data-uploadfield]").length){
        _updatename("[data-uploadfield] input[type='file']");
    }
});
```

---

### Solution 2

For CSS Only Solution

```css
.file_upload {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ee3333;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 2px #ee3333;
  font-weight: 600;
}

a.file_upload {
  display: inline-block;
}

.file_upload .btn_lbl {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.file_upload .btn_colorlayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.file_upload input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -86px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 100%;
  color: #ee3333;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="file_upload" type="button">
      <span class="btn_lbl">Browse</span>
      <span class="btn_colorlayer"></span>
      <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="file_upload" />
    </button>
```

Comment: Hi, I have removed demo link to your site as it might be considered as spam. Your demo can become invalid if the linked page is deleted. So, I have created a working snippet.

Comment: Looks completely broken in FF on Linux.

Comment: it's broken in Chrome too if you use czech language, which is longer in text

Answer (score 3):

I've had a long crack i hope it helps you may need to style it more to your liking

HTML

```
<form>
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file"     style="display:none;">
  <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="No File" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#uploadFile {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("file-upload").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

**JSFiddle link**:https://jsfiddle.net/kd1brhny/

Answer (score 0):

Upload button Style

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

Comment: Excellent Solution!

Comment: This doesn’t display the file name whatsoever and thus doesn’t answer the question.