# to have inline of the upload of the file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I  need to upload passport and photo but i want it to  be inline

```
<div id="upload">
   <div>
      <label for="Passportcopy">Passport Copy</label>
      <input type="file" id="Passportcopy">
   </div>
   <div >
      <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
      <input type="file" id="Photo">
   </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#passport{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:250px;
}

#photo{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    width:250px;        
}
```

I have used container with following css . 
is it bcz of div the block form of file upload will appear ?

```
label, input, div {
     display: block;         
}

input{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 40px;    
}
```

Or container having width or clear

```
.container {
     width:500px;
     clear:both;
}
.container input {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a native way to inline form elements in bootstrap using `form-inline` and `form-control` classes. You don't need to use any css if you use it in this way.
I have provided a snippet demonstrating it.

**Example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
       </head>
       <body>
       <div class="container">
      
  <div id="upload row">
  <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3 ">
      <label for="Passportcopy">Passport Copy</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Passportcopy">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Photo">
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can I reduce the size of the  of the photo and passport button .

Comment: Yes just manipulate `<div class="form-group col-xs-6">` add `col-xs-*` and if you want to achieve responsivness add all the responsive classes  `<div class="form-group col-xs-* col-sm-* col-md-* col-lg-*">` .....here `*` can be any value from 1 to 12

Comment: Check the updated snippet..it will clear your confusion about how to use bootstrap grid system as well...expand the screen size to see the effect..hope this helps!

Comment: styling file input is very difficult..although it's a very good source...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button]

Comment: I have a container of 500px which is at the centre.the above code snippet overlaps one label over the other .i tried changing to    col-xs-* the labels are not inline .

Comment: do you mean `width:500px;`?

Comment: if the width is 500px..it will automatically destroy the responsiveness of bootstrap..you need to use grid system..using width of px should never be used..bootstrap is developed to avoid such circumstances.

Comment: glad that it helped!

Comment: If an answer helps you consider upvoting it..if it solves your problem please click the green check mark to accept it..that's how SO works..otherwise people will think that the question is still open and it will attract spam answers.. at the same time if it didn't help you leave a comment to let people know that the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
 #passport{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:250px;
 }

 #photo{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    width:250px;
 }

#upload div{ /* new code */
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="upload">
  <div>
    <label for="Passportcopy">Passport Copy</label>
    <input type="file" id="Passportcopy">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
    <input type="file" id="Photo">
  </div>
</div>
```