# Styling an upload button for images and videos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to style my `input` as along these lines:

[image: Example]

Is there a way do style an `input` like this?

```
 <input id="fileupload" class="file-upload" name="media" type="file">

.file-upload {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.file-upload-input {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input id="fileupload" name="media" type="file">
<label for="file" class="file-upload">Choose a file</label>

<style>
#fileupload {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.file-upload {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #bd1a59;
}
.file-upload-input {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Live example:

```css
#fileupload {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.file-upload {
  color: white;
  width: 326px;
  padding: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ff4279;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input id="fileupload" name="media" type="file">
<label for="file" class="file-upload">Choose a File</label>
```

---

#### Reference:

- [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)