# Wordpress Contact Form 7 : How to custom file input upload?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to custom input files upload from CF7 in WP.

There are many ways to custom the button, but I need to display the file name once it has been uploaded.

I found one way to do it with this code :

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="custom-file-input">Your file</label>
```

And this script :

```
<script>
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
 var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
 $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
</script>
```

It works, but with CF7, we use shortcode te create inputs.

And it gives something like :

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
<input type="file" name="your-file" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file custom-file-input" id="your-file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
<label class="custom-file-label" for="your-file">Your file</label></div>
```

And it doesn't work anymore.
JS seems ok with the CF7 code.

Maybe it doesn't work because of CF7's way of generating code ?

I don't know.. Do you have an idea ?
Thank in advance for your help  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[file file-265 id:fileuploadfield class:fileuploadfield limit:120000 filetypes:.jpg .png 1/]
[text uploadtextfield id:uploadtextfield class:uploadtextfield]
<input type="button" id="uploadfile" value="select">
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your reply

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the minimum requirements of the guidelines.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button) answer may help.

Answer (score 0):

As CF7 wraps the field inside <span> first you need to look for the parent container (assuming .custom-file), and then look for the .custom-file-label.

```js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
    var filename = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).parents(".custom-file").find(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(filename);
});
```

This is kind of a late answer, but I was having this same issue today and this question helped me find the solution.