# How to style this button with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

There are two buttons in this page, "Select Files" button and "Subscribe Now" Button.

http://rafiee.heykado.com/upload-assignment/

The issue is that I can't style first button ("Select Files" button) to be exactly same as the other one.

This is the code I tried, but It's not working properly.

```
#input_1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0c0e71;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem in the question, don't just paste a link to your website - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: The buttons created by file upload fields are restricted in how much you can style them - a fact I’d rather have expected you to come across yourself while doing your research before asking. Solutions exist to replace them with custom elements that give you more freedom regarding the styling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score 0):

After checking your page, I noticed that this button is inside a Massey table!
However, if you want to style you "Select Files" button, I suggest that you do the following:

1. change < input .....> to < button >< /button >
2. along with you CSS above, add the "height"

   .input_1{
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #0c0e71;
       border-radius: 25px;
       height:35px;
       padding: 40px;
   }

Enjoy :)