# Styling an upload button input

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style button from auto generating form from php Nette framework.

I've tried for example

```
input[type="file" i] {
  display: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work...

**My upload button**

```css
#frm-categoriesForm-form-upload{
  background-color:#4e73df;
  width: 300px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="upload" id="frm-categoriesForm-form-upload" class="text">
```

I would like to change styles of "Choose File" and make it like "no file chosen"

Comment: take out the i from input[type="file" i]...

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: Appearance:none on your #frm-categoriesForm-form-upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button). See the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825731/10549827).