# Hide choose file button of input[type='file'] without hiding file choosen name with simple css

Tags: html, css, forms, input

If you're trying to remove the default Choose File Button without Removing the Filename label here is the simple CSS solution.

[image]

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314435/8620333 .. also you should write a valid question. SO is not a blog to share tuto or trick, it's a Q&A website. Even if you will answer your own question, it need to be a valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can easily remove choose file button of input type file without losing filename label with just simple CSS.

```
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[image]