# how to make select file in blue colour and also check box border in blue colour using html CSS and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make file chose background in blue colour and check box in blue colour using CSS html bootstrap any body help me out

```
  <form action="#" class="form-horizontal ws-validate">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Password*</label>
            <input type="file"  required />
        </div>
       
        <h2>Select icons</h2>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="">Variants
        </label>
    </form>
```

I want to create this type file choose background colour and checkbox border colour

<https://ibb.co/n8cVNbF   [https://ibb.co/TkWPFRq>](https://ibb.co/TkWPFRq%3E)
Create

[click](https://jsfiddle.net/soniii/zv6p3t5x/4/)

Comment: i want to make this type screen shot here https://ibb.co/n8cVNbF  https://ibb.co/TkWPFRq    any body help me out .i try this https://jsfiddle.net/soniii/zv6p3t5x/4/

Comment: you have to create custom element for those inputs. There is not ease way to just style them in css. Here is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button/25825731#25825731. This answer is for `file` but it is similar for `checkbox`. You can check http://icheck.fronteed.com/ to find and example of how to style checkboxes.