# How to remove the free space at the end of <input type="file">?

Tags: html, css, input

Why does `display: inline-block` not work properly for `<input type="file">`?

I would like the width of the element to be as wide as the content it's made of (button + text). But there's always some free space at the end of the text.

Why? And can this be fixed?

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/pWWdQ0y

Comment: You may want to check this out for a cross browser solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button/25825731#25825731

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is eligible for you, however it is possible to set `width` through CSS:

```css
input[type='file'] {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the width in percentage, it will work.

```
input[type='file'] {
  width: 36%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```