# How to customize input type file button in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was working on a simple form where I need to have a button to upload some file.
I am using bootstrap, I found that the typical way of making an input field of type file and assigning it classes like btn btn-success is not working as the way I wanted.

Cod:-

```
<label> Upload File : </label>
<input type="file" class=" btn btn-success form-control required" id="file" name="file" ng-model="Form.file" required>
```

The output of the following code is looking like -

[image]

I don't want the button to have this ugly text over "ChooseFile" No file chosen.
How can I make it normal button with a text over "Upload" with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For upload control beautification, I would suggest you to use [Dropify](https://jeremyfagis.github.io/dropify/) for form control and it is useful enough if you wish to do some validation.

Comment: Thank you, but dose that mean there is no way to do it in bootstrap only ?

Comment: You may refer to this example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546968/15764591