# React js customizing the input of type file using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an input of type file that needs to be customized. I need to add an icon in the input button, change the button's name and finally hide the selected file's name. I tried different methods like using a `<div>` or `<a>` but the problem is that I need to transfer the selected file to json format. So invoking the browsing action via JavaScript is causing an error in conversion. I need to use a customizable input of type file

```html
                    <input type="file"/>
```

How I need it to look

[image: Required shape]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with label and hiding the input.You need to of course style it properly and write a handleFile function.

```
 <div>
     <label onChange={handleFile} htmlFor="formId">
         <input name="" type="file" id="formId" hidden />
          <Icon>
     </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the HTML `label` tag and `htmlFor` property is the best solution for this.

**Step 1:**
Create a generic component to provide you with the functionality of file input.

```
// UploadControl.js

const UploadControl = ({ children, value, onChange, disabled, accept }) => {
  return (
    <label htmlFor="contained-button-file" className="m-0 w-100">
      <input
        value={value}
        accept={accept}
        disabled={disabled}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        id="contained-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
        onChange={disabled ? () => {} : onChange}
      />
      {children}
    </label>
  );
};
```

**Step 2:** Use this component by wrapping your custom-styled UI.

```
<button className="btn-styles">
   <UploadControl onChange={handleAddBanner} accept="image/*">
     Add New Banner
   </UploadControl>
</button>
```

**Step 3:** Implement a handler to get your file.

```
const handleAddBanner = ({ target: { files } }) => {
  const loadedImage = files[0];
  // loadedImage will be a image file.
};
```