# HTML input Type="file" button oversized, can't change width of button

Tags: html, css, input-type-file

I created this button in HTML to upload files:

`<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">`

I have two problems with it and I don't understand how to fix them

1. On the right side of the button it says "No file chosen", i have no problem with it being there, but for some reason I can click on the "No file chosen" text and even a bit to the right of the text and it will open the upload screen like it would do if I clicked on the button itself.
   How do I change it so it will click only on the button?

This is the button, anything inside the border counts as a click on it

[image]

2. How can I change the width of the button? I tried to use both `maxlength = "4"`  and `width = 40px` but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the button width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Comment: There is a really popular question on SO, with various possibilities on how to style an `input type="file"` element. If those don't fit your need you should explain why those methods don't work for you.

Comment: Generally file and checkbox inputs are pesky. You want to create a label element and style that instead. The label then has a for attribute that points to the input of type file. You style the input type file to display none.

Comment: couldn't find there something to fix the 1st problem, i was able to use it to create a border around the area that counts as the button, i changed the image to a new one which show it better

Answer (score 0):

**May be this will help you**

```html
 <style>
        div{
            background-color: gray;
            width: 400px;
        }
      input{
     box-sizing: content-box;
       max-width:180px;
     border:2px solid red;
             }
    </style>
    <div>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
    </div>
```

**Let me know if this wil work for you**.

Comment: when i do it this way it will not show me the name of the file i uploaded, i do want the area from the right to be there i just don't want it to be clickable

Comment: Now check and let me know is this what you want?

Comment: not yet, the part where it says "no file chosen" is still count as button there, i want to see the text but i don't want it to be clickable

Comment: @RoyShiff the file picker is not that customizable, you might want to build your own: https://jsfiddle.net/0y1bncLt/

Comment: so basically what i want to do with type:"file" is possible only with a custom button?