# Why does button block file selection?

Tags: css

Why does it block you to select a file when you click on the button? If you put a span or div in the label, they allow you to select a file when you click on them, but the button does not

```html
<html>
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="file">
    <button class="upload" type="button"></button>
  </label>
</body>

<style>
  label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 54px;

    background: green;
  }

  input {
    display: none;
  }

  .upload {
    background: gold;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: The `<input type="file">` is what's actually powering the upload, not the button. The button isn't really doing anything. Here's a pretty simple tutorial on how to style an upload button that may be of use: https://dev.to/faddalibrahim/how-to-create-a-custom-file-upload-button-using-html-css-and-javascript-1c03 but you're basically there with your label styling (the green box). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the `button` is a separate element it is not related to the input even if you wrapped them in one `label`

so to work around that you need to remove the button and style the label instead

CSS

```
label {
    /* style the input here  */
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 54px;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* more style .... */
}

input {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<label>
     select File
     <input type="file">
</label>
```