# How to style button for input type=file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hello I want to style the BUTTON with text `Choose files` that's generated as a result of `<Input type='file'/>` in Chakra UI

I gave it `id="file-input"` then styled it in CSS like so `#file-input {...}`

However, it styles the whole container - not the button itself.
After inspecting the button in chrome, it seems to be called `input#file-upload-button` however, after applying styles to this class it changes nothing.

How can I change that button saying 'Choose file' in Chakra UI or just CSS itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Comment: @Mina yes, thank you so much! I'll try to wrap the input element inside of label element and let you know

Comment: You should forst look at the pseudo class `::file-selector-button`