# Override User Agent Styling for Auto fill input fields

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How do i Override the default browser styling (light blue background) on input fields , I am doing the front end on angular ,

```
<input matInput formControlName="username" type="text" #userInput
        (cdkAutofill)="usernameAutofilled = $event.isAutofilled" [placeholder]="(usernameAutofilled || usernameFocused) ? '' : 'Username'" (blur)="onBlur($event,'username',authForm)" autocomplete="off" (focus)="usernameFocused =true" (keyup)="onKeyup('username')" />
```

i tried to override styling with webkit-autofill css property but that does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The [`:autofill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill) CSS pseudo-class matches when an `<input>` element has its value autofilled by the browser."

[Can I use `:autofill`?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_autofill) (currently 93.58% global support) shows that current versions of Chrome and Edge support it with the `-webkit-` prefix, but my testing proves that the prefix is not required.

If you want to include both for more browser support, two rulesets should be used instead of `input:-webkit-autofill, input:autofill {}` because a browser will ignore the entire rule if one of the comma-separated selectors is unsupported.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  outline: 3px solid firebrick;
}

input:autofill {
  outline: 3px solid firebrick;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="name">

  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email">

  <label for="country">Country</label>
  <input name="country" type="text" autocomplete="country-name">
</form>
```

I read my answer again and realized this would be a good case for the [`:is()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) because it accepts a forgiving selector list.

When using `:is()`, instead of the whole list of selectors being deemed invalid if one fails to parse, the incorrect or unsupported selector will be ignored and the others used.

[Can I use `:is(): Support for forgiving selector list?`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_is_forgiving_selector_list) currently shows 90.76% global support.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

input:is(:-webkit-autofill, :autofill) {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="name">

  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email">

  <label for="country">Country</label>
  <input name="country" type="text" autocomplete="country-name">
</form>
```