# Is there a way to change the color of the button in a file input?

Tags: css, html-input

For file inputs (`<input type="file">`) there is a button that says "Choose File".[image]

The color of it is gray, and I want to change that color. Since it technically is not a `<button>` element on its own, any styles that apply to `<button>` elements do not apply to this one. In the inspector, there is no indication that the button even exists, so the UA must provide it by default for file inputs. I did see a different button color on [Pinetools](https://pinetools.com/invert-image-colors) though, so it must be possible.

I have no idea how to do this, so any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button). In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528034/669576)

Answer (score -1):

yes,by adding css file you can change the color of the button.