# How to style HTML submit button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the "choose file" button in HTML using CSS styling and this does not work. The output I am achieving is in the screenshot below the HTML code - the button is not green (the same as the other buttons). Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? I would like to have the all of the buttons the same colour and font appearance. Am sure its a simple thing I am missing here - thanks in advance for help and guidance.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], inout[type=file] {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Styling form buttons</h2>
    
    <input type="button" value="Button">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="file" value="File">
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you have made a very small error. You typed `inout` instead of `input`. This fixed code should work:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=file] {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Styling form buttons</h2>
    
    <input type="button" value="Button">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="file" value="File">
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have a typo "inout" instead of "input"

check this page https://nikitahl.com/custom-styled-input-type-file page
this page give a good direction

start with

```
input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=file], input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the website - really useful.