Add Space between File Input button and Placeholder

I'm trying to add a space between the "Choose File" button and the "No file chosen" area. As seen in the photo above.
Here is my HTML:
<p class="mb-0 f-w-600">{{'BUSINESS_EDIT_LOGO' | translate}}</p>
<div class="file-input-container form-group mb-3">
  <input 
    class="form-control" 
    type="file" 
    formControlName="logo"
    (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)"
  >
</div>

Here is my CSS:
.form-control[type="file"]{
  gap: 15px;
}
  
.form-control[type="file"]::file-selector-button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

What I've tried is adding a margin beside the button, but that's not doing anything. I've also tried adding a gap, which isn't doing anything either

that's all apart of a single browser control so you may have to hide it and add your own components.

Styling <input> elements is very hard. As the comment above says, you might want to make a custom component. This answer describes how to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825731/18629913

Inspect the CSS class of that element , because there are some by default classes of that so there must be some spacing related things on that and try to override it according to your need . ( you may need to use !important to override )
