# CSS: How make the cursor to become a pointer on the input file?

Tags: jquery, css, file, textinput, onfocus

How can I make the cursor to become a pointer on an input file or an input text when you hover it?

My try but it does not work of course,

```
<input type="file" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

Or do I have to use javascrip (jquery)??

**EDIT:**

Sorry my mistake - the cursor does change to a point on

```
<input type="text" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

But not on

```
<input type="file" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

You can test [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/eq7y6/) on Firefox then you see what I mean.

Only the `button` of `file` change to the pointer but not the `input field` of `file`.

**EDIT 2:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HgYF4/1/) is my CSS 'hack',

```
<div id="right-col" style="position:relative; width:76px; height:24px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #000;">
<input type="file" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:2;opacity:1; cursor:pointer;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It does become a pointer for `input type="file"` when you mouse over the button, and for `input type="text"` when you mouse over the text field.

Comment: yes it is on the button but not when you mouse over the `input field` of `file`.

Comment: Don't believe this is possible. But *why on Earth* would you want to do that? The point of the text cursor is to show that you can enter text there...

Comment: basically it's browser implementation specific and not under your control.

Comment: When you click the textfield inside the file input, it behaves as if you clicked the button anyway, so might as well look like the same on the textfield as on the button. But alas not fixable in Firefox. Can be fixed in Chrome with ::-webkit-file-upload-button { cursor: pointer }

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23860302/1008999

Answer (score 4):

**Cannot be done.** The input type file is one of the most protected objects by the browsers. Some browsers allow you to do more things than others, depending on what they consider "safe".

You could use a **flash** button for it. In fact, there are very nice plugins written to make file uploading a nicer thing, such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: That is not styling an input file, that is hiding it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this ugly jQuery hack:

```
$('input:file').each(function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.before($('<div>').height($input.height()).width($input.width()).css(
        {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: $input.css('z-index')
        }).click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $input.click();
            $(this).show();
        }));
});
```

But it prevents the animation you normally see when you mousedown on a button element. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/eq7y6/1/)

Comment: thanks. a good hack but it does not work on opera - the dialog popup does not show anymore. see my edit above for my solution. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assign to the input `role="button"`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this works, for the asker and community's benefit?

Comment: @mjk, unfortunately I can't. I came across this question when I had this same issue and thought to write what it worked for me. I had the time to look a bit more into roles in HTML,  thanks to your comment, and I actually couldn't find any relation with css. I personally assigned ```role=button``` to the input because in my case that input had that role in my code (so correct from accessibility and semantic sides). Plus, it solved my issue of visually indicate to the user that that was actually a button (with the cursor: pointer), when nothing else was working. If you know more, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Nope... that's how you do it.  Compare [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L42LR/).

Comment: I'm on Firefox 6 and it does only apply to the button, not the text field next to it.

Comment: So tested in IE, it works, Chrome, it works, Firefox, it doesn't work. Sounds like a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an image instead, and do it like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/uploadButton.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />
<input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
});
```

**CAVEAT**:
In IE9 and IE10 if you trigger the onclick in a file input via javascript the form gets flagged as 'dangerous' and cannot be submmited with javascript, no sure if it can be submitted traditionaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  instead of any wrapper for input type "file".

```
<label for="photo"><span class="button">CHOOSE A FILE</span></label>
```

Check this ...
http://jsfiddle.net/pFK74/