# Change the cursor of an html <input> via css

Tags: css, input, cursor

I tried following to change the cursor of my html input tag (type="file"):

```
input{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

But it didn't work out. It remains the default cursor .. Why? Is it even possible to change it via css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: How make the cursor to become a pointer on the input file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155381/css-how-make-the-cursor-to-become-a-pointer-on-the-input-file)

Comment: Try to use ID selector or Class to handle it. And, Update your code with HTML to see what happen