# how to display pointer cursor over a "Browse" button

Tags: jquery, css

my last question on pointer cursors.

in Html you have a input file tag. This shows a textbox and a browse button. What I want to know is how can I display a cursor pointer when hovering over the "Browse" button?

Below is code:

```
var $videofile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'videoFile',
        id: 'videoFile'
    });
```

Comment: Can you show where the textbox and browse button are defined?

Comment: It's the standard layout for a file input in IE.  I believe it's a button and a label in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: mybe I'm missing the point but whats wrong with `style="cursor:pointer;"` on the element? Or a class with a css?

Comment: @Bazzz That makes it a pointer over the whole thing in IE and everything _but_ the button in other browsers.

Comment: You can't do *just* what you're asking.  If you do it in IE then the cursor is a pointer over both the textbox and the button.  All other browsers show a button and a label (no textbox), and the cursor turns to a pointer over the label, but not the button.  Look at this link to see how to style the file input so you can have more control over it...  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Short answer, [you can't][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var $videofile = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'file',
            name: 'videoFile',
            id: 'videoFile'
        }).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
```

Comment: Only works in IE and then the cursor is a pointer over the textbox as well as the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $videofile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'videoFile',
        id: 'videoFile'
    }).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
```

Comment: Only works in IE and then the cursor is a pointer over the textbox as well as the button.

Comment: Try this in a few browsers to see the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/pfKQf/2/  It *does not* make the cursor a pointer in anything but IE, over the button, but in IE it does it over the textbox as well.  There's no way to do this other than hiding the button and adding a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cursor` value in css:

```
var $videofile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'videoFile',
        id: 'videoFile'
    })
    .css('cursor','pointer');
```

Comment: See my comment - we need more information about how the markup looks to address that.

Comment: Only works in IE and then the cursor is a pointer over the textbox as well as the button.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is currently not possible without resorting to hacks. There is already [another thread on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file).