# element reference by id in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problem in referring to element in jQuery. 
I have some codes to evoke some action on other input entry by clicking another entry. It works fine to display the file name in the following codes.  However if I put the input entry inside a form tag, then the file name you select cannot be properly displayed. Could some experts explain how to make it work?

The following codes works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>


<style type='text/css'>
    input[type=file] {
    display:none
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    $('#btn_myFileInput').data('default', $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').text()).click(function () {
        $('#myFileInput').click()
    });
    $('#myFileInput').on('change', function () {
        var files = this.files;
        if (!files.length) {
            $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').text($('#btn_myFileInput').data('default'));
            return;
        }
        $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').empty();
        for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
            $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').append(files[i].name + '\n');
        }
    });
});
});

</script>
</head>   
<body>

<button id="btn_myFileInput">Choose file...</button>
<label for="btn_myFileInput">No file choosen or whatever...</label>
<input type="file" id="myFileInput" multiple/>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I don't know how to refer to the element correctly if the button is put inside a form tag. 
The following code will not show the selected file correctly:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<fieldset >

<button id="btn_myFileInput">Choose file...</button>
<label for="btn_myFileInput">No file choosen or whatever...</label>
<input type="file" id="myFileInput" multiple/>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

How to fix this problem please?

Comment: One thing, I think you should put the `style` and `script` elements into the `head` or `body`.  Right now there are floating in the middle of nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both `$(window).load()` and `$(function () {});`, since in your case they do the same thing. You could also add `return false` to the button click event, which probably will solve you problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/VzV7H/

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn_myFileInput').data('default', $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').text()).click(function () {
        $('#myFileInput').click();
        return false;
    });

    $('#myFileInput').on('change', function () {
        var files = this.files;
        console.log(files);
        if (!files.length) {
            $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').text($('#btn_myFileInput').data('default'));
            return;
        }
        $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').empty();
        for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
            $('label[for=btn_myFileInput]').append(files[i].name + '\n');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <button id="btn_myFileInput">Choose file...</button>
        <label for="btn_myFileInput">No file choosen or whatever...</label>
        <input type="file" id="myFileInput" multiple>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Update**

As @cernunnos pointed out in the comments, clicking an invisible `<input type="file">` from a `<button>` is likely to cause problems when using Internet Explorer.

[How to make IE8/9 submit input type="file" when javascript triggered dialog open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114024/how-to-make-ie8-9-submit-input-type-file-when-javascript-triggered-dialog-open)

Comment: Note that this solution will most likely cause problems when using Internet Explorer. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114024/how-to-make-ie8-9-submit-input-type-file-when-javascript-triggered-dialog-open for example

Comment: @cernunnos Very good addition to my answer! Something that should definitely be considered.

Comment: @user2818066 No problem. Please consider accepting this with the checkmark to the left if it answered your question.