# Why my on change event return empty on ie9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react.js and make a input tag with file type and also a onChange event like below.

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange}/>
```

In Chrome browser, everything is ok inside handleFileChange function, and I also can access to the event to get files informations like below

```
handleIDPosUploadChange: function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

However, in ie9 I cannot access to event, it return

```
Unable to get value of the property '0' : object is null or undefined
```

And I check in console of ie9, it seems e.target is {}.

Why this happened? Is ie9 support on change event?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that IE9 doesnt support file input types. Please use 
www.caniuse.com 
to check whether a particular thing is supported by that browser

Comment: thanks for reply, any other solution that can access file inout types in ie9 ?

Comment: please refer to this question in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114024/how-to-make-ie8-9-submit-input-type-file-when-javascript-triggered-dialog-open

Answer (score 0):

try onclick instead of onchange . IE not support on change

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>

var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var dataURL = reader.result;


alert(input.files[0].name);
      //var output = document.getElementById('output');
      //output.src = dataURL;
    };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 
//reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

  };
  </script>

<input onchange="openFile(event)" type="file">
```

I think this will work fine that working in IE 10.