# Why is my file input unaligned?

Tags: html, css, file, input

For some reason, when I use inspect element on my file input, it shows where it's supposed to be. But it doesn't behave that way. Go to oceankarma.co and click post at the top. Then try clicking the youtube icon. Please help

Comment: It's just the negative margins, nothing to worry about.

Comment: please post some relevant code and perhaps a self-contained code example. Otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: please post some code and ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but none of the existing answers helped me. Kind of like what koala_dev said, the inputs are overflowing. So I added a simple `overflow:hidden` style to the container and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

All the icons are of different dimensions. Youtube, Vimeo icons are placed in  tags while other black icons are used as background. This is causing the different styles.

1. Use same dimensions.
2. Same styles(except for background image so that everything is either called as background or everything via `<img>` tag)

If you do the above, it should give the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're referring to is that the the hidden file inputs are overflowing into the youtube link, try adding this to your CSS to fix it:

```
#servicetable tr td {
    position: relative;
}

#upload_video input, #upload_photo input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Also note that you cannot set the cursor property for file inputs. you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file) for more info