# Open file dialog box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, dialog

I need a solution to display open file dialog in HTML while clicking a `div`. The open file dialog box must open when the `div` is clicked.

I don't want to display the input file box as part of HTML page. It must be displayed in separate dialog, which is not a part of the web page.

Comment: An alert is not a file-dialog? - Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: i think he is saying he wants the standard "open file" popup

Comment: i need open file dialog box when a div is clicked. it must be as like alert which is not part of the web page

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here is a nice one

[Fine Uploader demo](http://fineuploader.com/demos)

It is an `<input type='file' />` control itself. But a div is placed over that and css styles are applied to get that feel. Opacity of the file control is set to 0 so that it appears that the dialog window is opened when clicking on the div.

Comment: is there a way to control the displayed files by javascript... say I wanted to open file dialog and just wanted file extension with .pdf to display..

Comment: @Ajax3.14 new browsers has the FileReader object, old browsers you gotta use the value and look for the file extension.

Comment: @Ajax3.14 No need to use FileReader or parse extensions. Many browsers support the accept attribute on file inputs. This allows you to limit the file types displayed in the file browser dialog. Fine Uploader provides access to this functionality via the acceptFiles property of the validation option. See the [validation section of the options documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#validation-option-properties) for more details. Note that the accept attribute is not supported in IE9 or earlier.

Comment: how come this is good? this is a good practice at all? shouldnt be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18659941/915865?

Comment: @KatLimRuiz No, the answer you linked to is not a good solution.  This will cause IE to throw an error if you end up submitting the associated form programmatically as well.

Comment: As of version 5.9.0, Fine Uploader is, once again, 100% free (MIT license).

Answer (score 90):

```js
    $("#logo").css('opacity','0');
    
    $("#select_logo").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#logo").trigger('click');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="select_logo">Select Logo</a> <input type="file" id="logo">
```

for IE add this:

```
$("#logo").css('filter','alpha(opacity = 0');
```

Comment: Why do you return false in the #select_logo click handler?

Comment: It wouldn't produce a 404 error, it would just try and navigate to the current page, with the # added at the end. Which would make the page jump to the top. So it's good to be there, just for a different reason :)

Comment: Though I haven't tested it enough, "visibility: hidden;" seems more compatible. In addition, despite the opacity: 0 a click event will trigger if the "invisible" element clicked, while visibility: hidden will not.

Comment: MDN indicates that `document.getElementById("logo").click()` is enough. They also show another way "Drag & Drop". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: You should convert this to normal Javascript, JQuery isnt logical to use on such a small project ^_^

Comment: @Tay - Nah... I like to use good old JQuery on even the smallest projects ^_^

Answer (score 69):

I dont't know why nobody has pointed this out but here's is a way of doing it without any Javascript and it's also compatible with any browser.

---

EDIT: In Safari, the `input` gets disabled when hidden with `display: none`. A better approach would be to use `position: fixed; top: -100em`.

EDIT 2: A different approach would be to use `opacity: 0`. The problem is that it can mess with the layout. I added some CSS to the example to illustrate the problem.

---

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px outset #ccc;
    border-radius: .3em;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    margin: .5em;
}

label:active {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Using <code>position: fixed</code>
  <input type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100%">
</label>

<label>
  Using <code>opacity: 0</code>
  <input type="file" style="opacity: 0">
</label>
```

If you prefer you can go the *"correct way"* by using `for` in the `label` pointing to the `id` of the input like this:

```html
<label for="inputId">file dialog</label>
<input id="inputId" type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em">
```

Comment: this works like charm, however, here are some recommendations: 1. `<input>` tag should have `name` attribute; 2. if `for` attribute is specified, `<input>` file tag will require a `id`.

Comment: `Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication`

Comment: great! it works like a charm even with a background image or making the label receive a click javascript triggered. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, someone pointed one catch with this solution, in Safari, inputs hidden with `display: none` are disabled. The workaround is using a different approach to hide the input. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JPdelaTorre It would be way better if you were to use opacity: 0 instead to hide the input.

Comment: @4dr14n31t0rTh3G4m3r You are absolutely right. I started using opacity lately and it is better.

Comment: It seems that this idea doesn't work anymore in the most modern browsers (just like how triggering `click()` doesn't work). Perhaps the new security requirements consider this to be an insecure method and prevents it from opening the file dialog.

Comment: @ADTC I just tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera to make sure, and it worked in all of them. I added a code snippet that can be run to test.

Comment: @JPdelaTorre thanks. Maybe I did something wrong and got confused.  The code snippet is helpful. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 51):

Actually, you don't need all that stuff with opacity, visibility, `<input>` styling, etc. Just take a look:

```
<a href="#">Just click me.</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function() {
        // creating input on-the-fly
        var input = $(document.createElement("input"));
        input.attr("type", "file");
        // add onchange handler if you wish to get the file :)
        input.trigger("click"); // opening dialog
        return false; // avoiding navigation
    });
</script>
```

Demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHVWp/). Tested in Chrome 30.0 and Firefox 24.0. Didn't work in Opera 12.16, however.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me; I just got <error> in the console in the middle of the jquery source; however input[0].click() works in Firefox 27.0.1, IE11.0.9600.17280 and Chrome 37.0.2062.120

Comment: This should be the correct answer. For pure Javascript implementation, do not need to modify any HTML code.

Comment: Silly question, but how would you get the chosen file afterwards?

Comment: Thanks for posting the jsFiddle demo. It helped me think of a browse button solution that is already implemented with IE input type=file but not in Chrome. The Chrome default is unacceptable.

Comment: How can this be tested with Selenium?

Comment: This is a dangerous solution that may result in unexpected issues. For example, some browsers (such as IE) may prevent a programmatic form submit if the file input is also programmatically opened. The best way to solve this problem is with CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: I find this awesome, don't need to use HTML, CSS. That should be the correct answer

Comment: @Charleston Unfortunately, it doesn't work in some browsers. They should make it work though :)

Comment: I tried to implement this to a non-jQuery solution but with little success. Ideas?

Comment: @BenjaminBrownlee Can we see your code? What in particular troubles you?

Comment: Fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745546/cannot-find-non-jquery-equivalent-for-trigger

Comment: This was my only solution, the others anwers does not work for me

Comment: As of 2020, this solution seems the nicest. Tested it on BrowserStack in Edge, Safari, Opera, Firefox, and Chrome. Works in all of them.

Comment: @JayWick Here is an example of how the data can be accessed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70514229/990349

Answer (score 31):

The simplest way:

```css
#file-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-input">
  <div>Click this div and select a file</div>
</label>
<input type="file" id="file-input"/>
```

What's important, usage of `display: none` ensures that no place will be occupied by the hidden file input (what happens using `opacity: 0`).

Comment: So simple and effective, I feel like it is the best solution for this!

Answer (score 19):

1. Put input element `type="file"` anywhere on page and hide it with `style="display:none"`. Give an id to input element. e.g. `id="myid"`.

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="myid"/>
```

2. Chose any div, image, button or any element which you want to use to open file dialog box, set an onclick attribute to it, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myid').click()"/>
```

Comment: This works very well. Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the approach: https://jsfiddle.net/0x4ydrzv/

Comment: I came here specifically bc I wanted to open the dialog using JS. For me it's not obvious that you can call click on an input element. Thx!

Comment: However it does not seem to work if the user does not actually click on something. For example calling click in the console does not and calling click in onload does also not work.

Answer (score 14):

This is what worked best for me (Tested on IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari).

```css
#file-input {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE < 9 */
  opacity: 0;
}
.input-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-input" class="input-label">
  Click Me <!-- Replace with whatever text or icon you wish to use -->
  <input type="file" id="file-input">
</label>
```

**Explanation:**
I positioned the file input directly above the element to be clicked, so any clicks would either land on it or its label (which pulls up the upload dialog just as if you clicked the label itself). I had some issues with the button part of the default input sticking out of the side of the label, so `overflow: hidden` on the input and `display: inline-block` on the label were necessary.

Comment: Maximize the input and and set opacity to zero. That works great!

Answer (score 13):

What if javascript is Turned Off on clients machine? Use following solution for all scenarios. You dont even need javascript/jQuery. :

**HTML**

```
<label for="fileInput"><img src="File_upload_Img"><label>
<input type="file" id="fileInput"></label>
```

**CSS**

```
#fileInput{opacity:0}  
body{
    background:cadetblue;
}
```

Explanation : `for="Your input Id"` . Triggers click event by default by HTML. So it by default triggers click event, no need of jQuery/javascript. If its simply done by HTML why use jQuery/jScript? And you cant tell if client disabled JS. Your feature should work even though JS is turned off.

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psko14e9/3/)** (You dont need JS , jquery)

Comment: Why the background?

Comment: Why opacity? Why not display: none;

Answer (score 12):

First add in the **head** tags:

```
<script>
   function showDialog(openFileDialog) {
       document.getElementById(openFileDialog).click();
   }
   function fileName(openFileDialog) {
       return document.getElementById(openFileDialog).value;
   }
   function hasFile(openFileDialog) {
       return document.getElementById(openFileDialog).value != "";
   }
   function fileNameWithoutFakePath(openFileDialog) {
       var fileName = document.getElementById(openFileDialog).value;
       return fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
   }
   function fakePathWithoutFileName(openFileDialog) {
       var fileName = document.getElementById(openFileDialog).value;
       return fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));
   }
</script>
```

if you already have **script** tags, just add these functions above.

In your **body** or **form** tags adding:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="yourDesiredOrFavoriteNameForTheNewOpenFileDialogInstance"/>
```

No matter where in your html, is just **like that** you've created a new instance of type OpenFileDialog class as **global** variable, whose name is the **id** of the element, no matter where in your code or xaml, **but** in your script or code, you **can't** type his name, and then read a property or call a function, because there are global functions that do those that are not defined in the element input type="file". You just have to give these functions the id of the hidden input type="file" which is the name of the OpenFileDialog instance as string.

To ease your life in creating open file dialogs instances to your html, you can make a function that does it:

```
function createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog(name) {
     document.getElementById("yourBodyOrFormId").innerHtml += "<input type='file' style='display:none' id='" + name + "'/>"
}
```

and if you want to remove open file dialog, then you can make and use the following function:

```
function removeOpenFileDialog(name) {
    var html = document.getElementById("yourBodyOrFormId").innerHtml;
    html = html.replace("<input type='file' style='display:none' id='" + name + "'/>", "");
    document.getElementById("yourBodyOrFormId").innerHtml = html;
}
```

but before you remove open file dialog, ensure that it exists by making and using the following function:

```
function doesOpenFileDialogExist(name) {
    return document.getElementById("yourBodyOrFormId").innerHtml.indexOf("<input type='file' style='display:none' id='" + name + "'/>") != -1
}
```

and if you don't want to create and add the open file dialogs in the **body** or **form** tags in the html, because this is adding hidden input type="file"s, then you can do it in script using the create function above:

```
function yourBodyOrFormId_onload() {
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("openFileDialog1");
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("openFileDialog2");
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("openFileDialog3");
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("File Upload");
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("Image Upload");
    createAndAddNewOpenFileDialog("bla");
    //etc and rest of your code
}
```

Ensure that near your body or form tags, you added:

```
onload="yourBodyOrFormId_onload()"
```

You don't have to do this line above, if you did it already.

**TIP:** You can add to your project or website new JScript File, if you don't have yet, and in this file you can put all the open file dialog functions away from the **script** tags and the html or web form page, and use them in your html or web form page from this JScript file, but don't forget before to link the html or web form page to the JScript File of course. You can do it just by dragging the JScript file to your html page in the **head** tags. If your page is web form and not simple html, and you don't have head tags, then put it anywhere so that it can work.
Don't forget to define global variable in that JScript File, whose value will be your body or form id as string. After you linked the JScript file to your html or web form page, you can onload event of your body of form, set the value of that variable to your body or form id. Then in the JScript File, you don't have to give to the document the id of the body or form of one page anymore, just give it the value of that variable. You can call that variable **bodyId** or **formId** or **bodyOrFormId** or any other name you want.

**Good luck man!**

Comment: It's best not to directly modify the innerHTML.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution I developed after I failed to find a good solution

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.setAttribute("multiple", true);
input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
input.onchange = function (event) {
    //
    console.log(this.files);
};
input.click();
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you still need an `<input type="file">` element, then you can use some of the stuff from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) to style it up

Answer (score 1):

The only without `<input type="file">` is by embedding a transparent flash movie over the div. You can then use a user generated click event (compliant with Flash 10 new security rules) to trigger a call to flash's [FileReference.browse](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html).

It offers an added dependency over the [quirksmode way](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) but in return you get alot more events (such as built in progress events).

Comment: After more than 11 years, I get to say that **this will no longer work.** 

Answer (score 0):

May use

```
$('<input type="file" />').click()
```

Comment: in my case, this causes an automatic redirection to the same page where the original click event happened - making the whole page reload and lose all data previously entered in the page.